# XmlDiscriminatorNode, XmlSchema namespace, and elementFormDefault=QUALIFIED

Tags: java, eclipselink, moxy

I'm using eclipselink-2.3.2. My package is annotated:

`@XmlSchema(namespace = "http://example.com/namespace", elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)`

I have the following classes:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Box {
    private A item; // and getter/setter
}

@XmlDiscriminatorNode("@thetype")
public abstract class A {}

@XmlDiscriminatorValue("b")
public class B extends A {}

@XmlDiscriminatorValue("c")
public class C extends A {}
```

When I try to deserialize valid XML like this:

`<box xmlns="http://example.com/namespace"><a thetype="b" /></box>`

I get the descriptive exception:

```
org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: Missing class indicator field from database row [UnmarshalRecord()]
```

If I remove the `@XmlSchema` from the package and the `xmlns` attribute from the root element, it works. If I change from QUALIFIED to UNQUALIFIED, it works as long as I feed it the ugly prefixed XML.

I assumed that the unprefixed would work since it still declares the default namespace, but although there is no exception the field remains null.

After stepping through the EclipseLink code, I can see that when `QNameInheritancePolicy.classFromRow` calls `UnmarshalRecord.get`, it is trying to access the attribute "thetype" under the namespaceURI "http://example.com/namespace".

When I change the XmlScehma elementFormDefault to UNQUALIFIED, the namespaceURI comes back null and the attribute is properly retrieved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php).  You can track our progress on this issue using the link below.  I already have a fix attached to the bug, I'll check it in once the test cases have finished running.

- http://bugs.eclipse.org/377967

**UPDATE**

This bug has now been fixed.  You can try it out by obtaining one of the EclipseLink 2.4.0 nightly builds starting April 30th, 2012:

- http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/downloads/nightly.php

Comment: One strange thing is that earlier we had an attribute storing the value of an enum that we're using as the @XmlDiscriminatorNode and when both the attribute and annotation specify the same name the attribute appears twice in the XML, causing XML parsers to barf. I would expect that we'd get an exception instead when the class is loaded into the JAXBContext.

Answer (score 1):

Your discriminator is an attribute, so I think you just need to add an "@":

```
@XmlDiscriminatorNode("@thetype")
public abstract class A {}
```

This [blog post by Blaise Doughan](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/11/jaxb-and-inheritance-moxy-extension.html) contains some more information and an example.

Comment: Sorry; that's my fault for coming up with a contrived example. I've edited the question.

Comment: (in fact, that blog post is exactly the case I reproduced, except that I begin to have problems when I add the XmlSchema)